# Why CFMessagePortCreateRemote always return NULL?

Tags: macos, cocoa, ipc, mach

I used to use CFMessagePortRef to communicate between 2 processes on Mac os. It works well. In one process, I use CFMessagePortCreateLocal to create port, set callback and add it into run loop. In another process, I use CFMessagePortCreateRemote to get the port and send data by CFMessagePortSendRequest.

Now for whatever reason, it stops working. The call CFMessagePortCreateRemote always returned NULL. But CFMessagePortCreateLocal in another process returns valid value.

My system is Catalina 10.15.3. And both processes are not sandboxing. There is no clear error in Console app. I checked Apple docs and didn't get any luck. I googled and didn't get any helpful information. Can anyone know what's going on? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

System(10.15+) denied it, need find other replacement